# CodeIgniter - Changing a regular query to an active record query

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering if someone could show me how to change the following sql query to codeigniters active record structure?

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table_name.' WHERE firstname LIKE "%'.$searchterm.'%" OR lastname LIKE "%'.$searchterm.'%"');
return $query->result();
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->db->like('firstname', $searchterm);
$this->db->or_like('lastname', $searchterm); 
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);

return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name)->like('firstname', $searchterm)->or_like('lastname', $searchterm);
```

For more information on CodeIgniter's database library, [see this documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).